# Elasticsearch response to include items coditionally

Tags: node.js, database, elasticsearch, query-string, elasticsearch-dsl

I need to remove some extra data that I am getting in the response, but this data needs to be removed conditionaly, so a plain incude or exclude might not work

```
GET /houseId/_search
{
    "_source": {
        "include": ["name","labels"]
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "cloud_id.keyword": [
                            "something"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The query above returns the below response

```
{
  ...
  "hits" : {
    ...
    "hits" : [
    {
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "peter",
          "labels" : [
            {
              "value" : "true",
              "key" : "active"
            },
            {
              "value" : "103",
              "key" : "pool-id"
            }
          ]
        }
      },

      {
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "john",
          "labels" : [
            {
              "value" : "true",
              "key" : "active"
            },
            {
              "value" : "205",
              "key" : "pool-id""
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The documents returned are correct, However, I need to remove some extra data that i am getting in th`labels` field. I only want the key and value where the key is `pool-id`. So that `labels` could look something like below

```
"labels" : {
              "value" : "205",
              "key" : "pool-id""
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

To return only the documents having `"key": "pool-id"` in `labels` object, you need to define an explicit mapping, and map `labels` to be of nested type.

And then use [inner_hits with nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html) to return only the matched `nested` object.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "labels": {
                "type": "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "_source": {
        "include": [
            "name",
            "labels"
        ]
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "cloud_id.keyword": [
                            "something"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "labels",
                        "query": {
                            "term": {
                                "labels.key.keyword": "pool-id"
                            }
                        },
                        "inner_hits": {}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "72821655",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.6931471,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "peter",
                    "labels": [
                        {
                            "value": "true",
                            "key": "active"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "103",
                            "key": "pool-id"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inner_hits": {
                    "labels": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 1,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 0.6931471,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "72821655",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "labels",
                                        "offset": 1
                                    },
                                    "_score": 0.6931471,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "value": "103",
                                        "key": "pool-id"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "72821655",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.6931471,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "john",
                    "labels": [
                        {
                            "value": "true",
                            "key": "active"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "205",
                            "key": "pool-id"           // note this
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inner_hits": {
                    "labels": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 1,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 0.6931471,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "72821655",
                                    "_id": "2",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "labels",
                                        "offset": 1
                                    },
                                    "_score": 0.6931471,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "value": "205",
                                        "key": "pool-id"          // note this
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```